# How to allow only numbers and *[star] in string validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to allow only numbers and * [Stars] while performing string Validation. This below snippet is working for numbers only. How to do both numbers and stars include.

```
 const isNumeric = (value) => {
        return /^-?\d+$/.test(value);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const regex = /[\d*]+/g;

const test = "1233*";

const isNumeric = (value) => /^[\d*]+$/.test(value);
console.log(isNumeric(test));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isNumeric = (value) => {
    return /^-?[\*\d]+$/.test(value);
};
```

inside regEx please add string in ur function does the job :)